# Undeletable answers on locked questions don't show as undeletable in 10k tools

Tags: bug, 10k-tools, vote-to-delete, locked-questions

In the 10k tools, an answer with a delete vote on a locked (but open - not sure if thats important though) question shows as not-greyed out for a 20k user, however the answer is not deletable because the question is locked.

[image: Some delete votes]

Compare with the locked question:

[image: another delete vote I can't do anything about]

However, following the link to [How can I Improve my problem-solving ability](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/35594/how-can-i-improve-my-problem-solving-ability/38594#38594) shows a locked undeletable answer:

[image: A locked question]

The locked answers should similarly show as not delete voteable as the locked questions are.